# Button background image is not showing from resource of another application

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two Application A1 and A2. In A1 i have button.xml inside drawable folder.In A2 i have a button and i want to set b ackground image of the button as button.xml 
Code I am using:

```
Context otherAppContext = getApplicationContext()
                    .createPackageContext("com.gincy.A1",
                            Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
int drawableResourceId = otherAppContext.getResources().getIdentifier("button",
            "drawable", otherAppContext.getPackageName());
button_layout.setBackground(drawableResourceId);
```

I am using the above code and it will show the error

```
09-15 06:44:30.469: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 06:44:30.469: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020058
09-15 06:44:30.469: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
09-15 06:44:30.469: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:658)
09-15 06:44:30.469: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:14179)
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawableResourceI);
```

You cannot set an Id as background, you use the id of that drawable to get it from resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this:

```
Drawable anotherAppDrawable = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("com.gincy.A1").getDrawable("button");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have passed resource's id instead of actual Drawable item of resource to be set in back ground. So try this. Hope it will help you.

Instead of using

```
int drawableResourceId = otherAppContext.getResources().getIdentifier("button",
        "drawable", otherAppContext.getPackageName());
button_layout.setBackground(drawableResourceId);
```

Try using

```
button_layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button));
```

Comment: And do not forget to initialize "button_layout".

Comment: Your most welcome and if you found this answer useful than you can vote it up